# String array contents become null except the last index

Tags: android, arrays, json, string, null

Im using json to parse data,

```
{
"userDetails": [
    {
        "id": "186",
        "username": "manoj",
        "status": "1"
    },
    {
        "id": "189",
        "username": "anu",
        "status": "1"
    },
    {
        "id": "190",
        "username": "manojsoyal",
        "status": "1"
    },
    {
        "id": "191",
        "username": "mohit",
        "status": "1"
    },
    {
        "id": "192",
        "username": "micky",
        "status": "1"
    },
    {
        "id": "193",
        "username": "preet",
        "status": "1"
    },
    {
        "id": "194",
        "username": "mohit",
        "status": "1"
    },
    {
        "id": "195",
        "username": "mohit",
        "status": "1"
    },
    {
        "id": "196",
        "username": "harold",
        "status": "1"
    },
    {
        "id": "197",
        "username": "sukhi",
        "status": "1"
    },
    {
        "id": "198",
        "username": "harold2",
        "status": "1"
    },
    {
        "id": "199",
        "username": "sukhi",
        "status": "1"
    },
    {
        "id": "200",
        "username": "neha",
        "status": "1"
    },
    {
        "id": "201",
        "username": "jay",
        "status": "1"
    },
    {
        "id": "202",
        "username": "qwe",
        "status": "1"
    }
]
```

}

and this is my code

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

```
final static String URL = "this is the url";

String appUsernames[] = null;
String appUserIDs[] = null;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
    JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(URL);

    try {
        JSONArray userDetails = json.getJSONArray("userDetails");
        for (int i = 0; i < userDetails.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject c = userDetails.getJSONObject(i);

            String name = c.getString("username");
            String id = c.getString("id");

            appUsernames = new String[userDetails.length()];
            appUserIDs = new String[userDetails.length()];

            appUsernames[i] = name;
            appUserIDs[i] = id;

            Log.d("First", appUserIDs[i] + ": " + appUsernames[i]);

        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < appUserIDs.length; i++) {
        Log.d("Second", appUserIDs[i] + ": " + appUsernames[i]);
    }
}
```

}

on my first log.d the string array is not empty. But in the second log.d it appears to be null except for the last index of the string array. What is happening? Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 appUsernames = new String[userDetails.length()];
 appUserIDs = new String[userDetails.length()];
```

move the creation of the arrays outside the for loop

```
try {
        JSONArray userDetails = json.getJSONArray("userDetails");
        appUsernames = new String[userDetails.length()];
        appUserIDs = new String[userDetails.length()];
        for (int i = 0; i < userDetails.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject c = userDetails.getJSONObject(i);

            String name = c.getString("username");
            String id = c.getString("id");

            appUsernames[i] = name;
            appUserIDs[i] = id;

            Log.d("First", appUserIDs[i] + ": " + appUsernames[i]);
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```